# what is the difference between these two ways of filtering a pandas dataframe for sklearn classifier?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the same pandas data frame like this (there are a lot more columns the rest are numeric).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['2013-08-01 00:00:00', '2014-09-01 12:10:00', '2015-02-02 10:10:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00'], 'Model_Targ':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'Col2':[-0.945000, -0.855000, -0.860000, -0.945000], 'Col3':[64.384028, 64.485417, 64.609028, 64.723611]})
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

TrainSet = df[df['Time']<'2015-01-01']
TestSet = df[df['Time']>'2015-01-01']
```

if I process it using

```
Train_Y = TrainSet.iloc[:, 1]
Train_X = TrainSet.drop(TrainSet.columns[[0,1]], axis=1)

Test_y = TestSet.iloc[:,1]
Test_x = TestSet.drop(TestSet.columns[[0,1]], axis=1)
```

it works fine in Sklearns `DummyClassifier()`
if I process it using

```
Columns_to_drop = df.filter(like='Targ', axis = 1).columns.values.tolist()
Columns_to_drop.append('Time')

Train_Y = TrainSet.filter(like='Targ', axis = 1)
Train_X = TrainSet.drop(Columns_to_drop, axis=1)

Test_y = TestSet.filter(like='Targ', axis = 1)
Test_x = TestSet.drop(Columns_to_drop, axis=1)
```

I get an error in the dummy classifier.

```
clf = DummyClassifier()
clf.fit(Train_X , Train_Y)
Predict_y = clf.predict(Test_x)
```

I have compared the two frames and it returns a giant matrix of `TRUE`

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/dummy.pyc in predict(self, X)
    174 
    175             elif self.strategy == "stratified":
--> 176                 ret = proba[k].argmax(axis=1)
    177 
    178             elif self.strategy == "uniform":

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'argmax'
```

Comment: where does 'TestSet` come from? Your code is not verifiable, please add the proper imports and create an example that runs.

Comment: it's a split from the original df. Do you have any tips on how to provide more without having to work out a way to anonymize 70 columns or a better way to generate a sample frame?

Comment: Can you make a code that works? Then I can give it a try.

Comment: okies edited and tested twice to make sure it does what my program does

Comment: Your code to show that it works one way, would have never worked because you indexed it incorrectly. That said, I was able to replicate your problem doing it the second way, even in 0.18...see answer for fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to show that it works doesn't work because you indexed your test and train sets incorrectly. That code should be this instead:

```
#! Index([u'Col2', u'Col3', u'Model_Targ', u'Time'], dtype='object')
Train_Y = TrainSet.iloc[:, 2]
Train_X = TrainSet.drop(TrainSet.columns[[2,3]], axis=1)

Test_y = TestSet.iloc[:,2]
Test_x = TestSet.drop(TestSet.columns[[2,3]], axis=1)
```

Now, the reason it doesn't work in your second code example, is because you are returning DataFrames to your target sets (Train_Y,Test_y). This is a problem, because the DummyClassifier `predict` method, calls the `argmax` method, which DataFrames themselves don't have, but their columns, which are Series, do. So, to get your second code example working, you just need to specify the column name to pull out the Series.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['2013-08-01 00:00:00', '2014-09-01 12:10:00', '2015-02-02 10:10:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00'], 'Model_Targ':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'Col2':[-0.945000, -0.855000, -0.860000, -0.945000], 'Col3':[64.384028, 64.485417, 64.609028, 64.723611]})
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

TrainSet = df[df['Time']<'2015-01-01']
TestSet = df[df['Time']>'2015-01-01']

Columns_to_drop = df.filter(like='Targ', axis = 1).columns.values.tolist()
Columns_to_drop.append('Time')

Train_Y = TrainSet.filter(like='Targ', axis = 1)['Model_Targ'] #!
Train_X = TrainSet.drop(Columns_to_drop, axis=1)

Test_y = TestSet.filter(like='Targ', axis = 1)['Model_Targ'] #!
Test_x = TestSet.drop(Columns_to_drop, axis=1)

clf = DummyClassifier()
clf.fit(Train_X , Train_Y)
Predict_y = clf.predict(Test_x)
print Predict_y
```